# How to Change Button Icon to Animated Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

I am Facing Some Issues on this Topic. I have a Material Button. as you can see in the Code below there is an "Emoticon" icon is Set for it.

```
            MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    // color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

I also Have a Text Field which Looks like, this, (below),

```
                TextFormField(
                  // autofocus: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Write Task',
                    // border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ),
```

After the user is done writing I need to Show up this `List` of emojis `[,,,,,,]` One by one in the Delay of One Second. inside the Material Button, Place Above, in the place of Icon.

1. I have a Material Button
2. I have an Icon Inside it.
3. I also Have a Text Field
4. After TextField is Done Writing, I need to Show `List` of emojis `[,,,,,,]`
5. I want to replace the Icon in the Material Button.
6. And I want to Show a Slide Show of These Emojis Except the Button's Icon
7. Also If user Clicks on Emoji the Emoji Gets Locked, or Store in Some kind of Variable

I really want to Seek Help at this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here,

- Initially one icon is shown in material button. As per the user's interaction the icon will be changed.
   To achieve this, create instance of `IconData` (as `Icon` accepts `IconData`) and initially set the default icon. You can set the selected `IconData` to the variable whenever user selects another icon.
- I don't know whether this traditional icons are there in Material Icons library or not. Check [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) otherwise.